Using MEMBER OF function when nested table having multiple columns
Have used MEMBER OF function multiple times successfully when the nested table having only one column. But now have a situation that the nested table having multiple columns.
Is it possible to use the MEMBER OF function when COLUMN2 value matches from TABLEA then return corresponding COLUMN1 value.
Nested table (TABLEA)



Column1
Column2




1
AA


2
BB


3
CC


4
DD



Below code is erroring out. Please assist how to proceed on this scenario.
IF 'AA' MEMBER OF TABLEA.COLUMN2 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLEA.COLUMN1);
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT Found.');
END IF;


MEMBER OF is used on collections and columns. Use select query instead

Please edit your question to include a [mre]. You've shown one small code snippet but haven't shown how TABLEA is defined, declared or populated, or even what error you get.

Add a MAP MEMBER FUNCTION to the object so that you can compare on the mapped column:
CREATE TYPE obj_type IS OBJECT(
  column1 NUMBER,
  column2 VARCHAR2(10),

  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION compare RETURN VARCHAR2
);

CREATE TYPE BODY obj_type
IS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION compare RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS 
  BEGIN
    RETURN column2;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TYPE obj_tab_type IS TABLE OF obj_type;

Then you can use:
DECLARE
  tablea obj_tab_type := obj_tab_type(
    obj_type(1, 'AA'),
    obj_type(2, 'BB'),
    obj_type(3, 'CC'),
    obj_type(4, 'DD')
  );
BEGIN
  IF obj_type(1, 'AA') MEMBER OF TABLEA THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not Found.');
  END IF;
END;
/

Which outputs:
Found


If you want to check the value without a MAP function then use a query:
DECLARE
  tablea obj_tab_type := obj_tab_type(
    obj_type(1, 'AA'),
    obj_type(2, 'BB'),
    obj_type(3, 'CC'),
    obj_type(4, 'DD')
  );
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    found NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO   found
    FROM   TABLE(tablea)
    WHERE  column2 = 'AA'
    AND    ROWNUM = 1;
  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not Found.');
  END;
END;
/

or a loop:
DECLARE
  tablea obj_tab_type := obj_tab_type(
    obj_type(1, 'AA'),
    obj_type(2, 'BB'),
    obj_type(3, 'CC'),
    obj_type(4, 'DD')
  );
  found BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. tablea.COUNT LOOP
    IF tablea(i).column2 = 'AA' THEN
      found := TRUE;
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF found THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
  ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not Found.');
  END IF;
END;
/

fiddle
